# PHP: RFC-2231 How to encode UTF-8 String as Content-Disposition filename

Tags: php, content-disposition, rfc2231

Scenario: (in PHP) I have a form submission with a **UTF-8** encoded string (`$name`) to support international characters. Upon submitting the form (via GET), I am creating a CSV download file. I want the name of the file to be that *string* + `.csv`  (`"$name.csv"`). For a western character set I can do this just fine by doing:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$name\"");
```

But for other character sets, the download file's name is *garbage letters* + `.csv` (such as `×œ×œ× ×›×•×ª×¨×ª.csv`). I am trying to follow RFC 2231 to do something like:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename*=UTF-8''$name");
```

But I seem to have a couple problems:

1. Browser seems to ignore the "*filename*" part of the header. Is my format right?
2. I need to encode each character of `$name` octets encoded in hexadecimal, like "`This%20is%20%2A%2A%2Afun%2A%2A%2A`". Does anyone have a function to do this properly? I coded the following but I don't think it is right:

   ```
   $fileName = encodeWordRfc2231($name) . ".csv";
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename*=UTF-8''$fileName");

   function &encodeWordRfc2231($word) {
       $binArray = unpack("C*", $word);
       foreach ($binArray as $chr) {
           $hex_ary[] = '%' . sprintf("%02X", base_convert($chr, 2, 16));
       }
       return implode('', $hex_ary);
   }
   ```

Does anyone out there have experience with this and can set me on the right path?

Comment: Internally PHP uses string-builders for strings, so storing the string pieces in `$hex_ary` is unnecessary. You should just use a `$hex = '';` then append each piece to it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968272/how-can-i-encode-with-rfc-2231-a-filename-in-php

Answer (score 13):

It is enough to encode the file name according to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) by using [rawurlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php)

So all you need to do is change the header() line to:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename*=UTF-8''".rawurlencode($name));
```

To answer the questions directly:

1. The format is right but the text inside $name needs to be encoded with [rawurlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php).
2. [rawurlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) does the trick.