# How can i encode urls in a safe way in order to use them in a mail header "location" in php?

Tags: php, urlencode

How can i encode urls in a safe way in order to use them in a mail header "location" in php?

Is `urlencode` enough? May I use [rfc2231_encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968272/how-can-i-encode-with-rfc-2231-a-filename-in-php)?

Comment: What do you mean by "mail header location"? I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

I have never had a problem using urlencode and urldecode