# How can I decode a string that has been encoded using RFC2231 using PHP

Tags: php, mime, rfc2231

I am parsing MIME formatted emails which have attachments. The attachments have their filenames encoded using RFC2231, so for example the 'content-disposition' of one of the attached files is:

```
attachment;  filename*=utf-8''Bill%20Sixteen.pdf
```

How do I go about decoding that filename?

Comment: @rekire I'd agree in theory, but in practice that doesn't really lead to an answer.

Comment: This one's better: [How can I encode a filename in PHP according to RFC 2231?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968272/how-can-i-encode-a-filename-in-php-according-to-rfc-2231)

Comment: I am looking to decode a RFC2231 string, rather than encode into this format.

Comment: @deceze I was just adding that link

Comment: @deceze - The duplicates that are referenced are for _encoding_ rather than _decoding_.  I am looking do decode.

Comment: What exactly is your question? You already know about RFC 2231, and it explains the format of that encoding, so all you have to do is follow that RFC. If you're asking for recommendations for existing libraries for parsing RFC2231-encoded strings, you're asking on the wrong site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the specific method out of the akelos framework as mentioned by Dukeatcoding.

```
/**
 * RFC 2231 Implementation
 */
public function _decodeHeaderAttribute($header_attribute, $charset = '')
{
    if(preg_match("/^([A-Z0-9\-]+)(\'[A-Z\-]{2,5}\')?/i",$header_attribute,$match)){
        $charset = $match[1];
        $header_attribute = urldecode(str_replace(array('_','='),array('%20','%'), substr($header_attribute,strlen($match[0]))));
    }
    return Ak::recode($header_attribute, 'UTF-8', $charset);
}
```

See how they do it and create your own decode function using that ;)

P.S. I believe that the akelos framework uses the LGLP license - so be warned should you use that method as is in your own project.

Answer (score 1):

The akelos Framework does seem to have a decoding function you might look into it:

[Akelos](http://www.akelos.org/api/elementindex_AkelosFramework.html)