# utf-8 character recognition issue

Tags: php, intranet

**download.php**

```
} else {
    $filename = NULL;
}

$err = '<div align="center">GREEK error msg</div>';

if (!$filename) {
    // if variable $filename is NULL or false display the message
    echo $err;
} else {
    // define the path to your download folder plus assign the file name
    $path = '../downloads/'.$filename;

    // check that file exists and is readable
    if (file_exists($path) && is_readable($path)) {
        // get the file size and send the http headers
        $size = filesize($path);
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream;');
        header('Content-Length: '.$size);
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        // open the file in binary read-only mode
        // display the error messages if the file can´t be opened
        $file = @ fopen($path, 'rb');
        if ($file) {
            // stream the file and exit the script when complete
            fpassthru($file);
            exit;
        } else {
            echo $err;
        }
    } else {
        echo $err;
    }
}
?>
```

and this is how I call it:

```
<a href="scripts/download.php?file=GREEKCHARS_Earth.pdf"></a>
```

1. If file name is in English download script works ok.
   If file name is in Greek it shows the error msg.
2. If I **echo $filename** I see the correct Greek name so I suppose that the correct name is passed in my download.php.
3. Since I get **the correct name with $filename** and my actual file has the same name, where does the script fails to download my file and it gives me the error msg?

It seems that it fails to match the Greek $filename with the actual file.

Comment: Try `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.rawurlencode($filename));`

Comment: There are many points at which this can screw up. First of all, is the value received correctly by the server? Try `bin2hex()`ing the `$_GET` value and check if those are the actual UTF-8 bytes for "ΔΨΞ" (`CE94CEA8CE9E`).

Comment: @deceze `echo bin2hex($_GET) . "<br />";` outputs nothing. `echo bin2hex($filename) . "<br />";` outputs: cea42ece942e5f3039385f

Comment: And what is the string that produced `cea42ece942e5f3039385f`?

Comment: ok. **Τ.Δ._003_GammaRAE_II_R** output **cea42ece942e5f3030335f47616d6d615241455f49495f522e706466**

Comment: @deceze can you think of anything else to test? thank you.

Comment: Well, that's UTF-8, alright. It's only screwing up on the receiving end, as the name for the file? That says the client is misinterpreting the encoding of the filename, which is not terribly surprising since there's no indication whatsoever in the response what encoding is being used. I'm not sure, but maybe try adding `; charset=utf-8` to the `Content-Type` header?

Comment: @deceze **application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8;** if this is correct syntax then is not working either.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that HTTP headers may only contain ASCII characters. That's the standard, since the headers are there to define what content is following in what encoding, the headers themselves cannot contain characters in some yet-unspecified encoding.

To send non-ASCII symbols in the header, they need to be encoded according to RFC 2231.
See this answer here: [How can I encode a filename in PHP according to RFC 2231?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968272/how-can-i-encode-a-filename-in-php-according-to-rfc-2231)

Comment: Hm.. I have never seen this. Can you explain me WHERE/HOW to use it? Thank you.

Comment: When used the `bin2hex()` for `$filename` I got utf-8 result. But `<a href="scripts/download.php?**file=GREEKCHARS_Earth.pdf**">` is sending the filename as **!#!#!#_EARTH.pdf** Is this something different?

Comment: Instead of `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=ΔΨΞ`, which is illegal according to the HTTP specs, you're supposed to send something like `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=title*0*=utf-8...`. So just modify that line where you set the `header()`.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "is sending the file name as..."?

Comment: Firebug shows the above url that has **file=GREEKCHARS_Earth.pdf** as **file=!#!#!#_EARTH.pdf** so I am asking if there is a php code that can be placed so the url gets the correct format.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does not show "!#!#". It's probably *URL encoded*, which looks like `%42%42...`. That's normal, since URLs cannot contain non-ASCII characters either.

Comment: oh ok... yes the #!#!#! was just my typing. is url encoded what it shows.

Comment: Hi again. if I echo $filename (in my download.php) I get the correct greek name file. this means that the correct name is passed to my download.php Isn't it? If not it means is passing this: %CE%A4.%CE%94._003_GammaRAE_II_R.pdf Is there a way to decode this in my download.php and continue from there? Thank you

Comment: "%CE%A4.%CE%94._..." is *URL encoding*. PHP will automatically decode this for all values in `$_GET` or `$_POST`. If you take the filename from there, you don't need to decode it. Otherwise: [`urldecode`](http://php.net/urldecode).

Comment: Then since my $filename is correct where does the download.php gets lost and doesn't find my file?

Comment: I'm getting lost on what the problem is. Is it not finding the file? Is it not setting the filename correctly upon download? Both? Something else? If you're confused about the basics of encodings, a few articles on http://kunststube.net may help you get up to speed.