# PHP Content-Disposition header: Specialcharacters in the filename

Tags: php, encoding, http-headers

I am trying to download a file with php that has special characters in the file name.
Unfortunately these characters are substituted by "_".

The code:

```
$filename = trim('<>$%&/=?' . '.txt');

header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 200 OK");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Type: application/text");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; '
        . sprintf('filename="%s"; ', urlencode($filename))
        . sprintf("filename*=utf-8''%s", urlencode($filename)));
echo "file contents";
die();
```

returns a file named

```
"__$%&_=_.txt"
```

I have tried different variations with urlencode(), rawurlencode(), mb_convert_string($filename, "UTF-8").
The already present issues [Special Characters in Content-Disposition filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967079/special-characters-in-content-disposition-filename), [How to encode the filename parameter of Content-Disposition header in HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http) and [PHP: RFC-2231 How to encode UTF-8 String as Content-Disposition filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856362/php-rfc-2231-how-to-encode-utf-8-string-as-content-disposition-filename) did not really help me.
Do you have any further ideas?

Encoding of the file is UTF-8.

Sprintf() seems not to be the problem:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename*=utf-8''" . rawurlencode($filename));
```

or

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename . "\"");
```

give the same result.

Comment: `sprintf()` and the like aren't unicode-aware. they WILL mangle multibyte text. there is no mb_*() equivalent for sprintf either. you'll have to use other means.

Comment: Thank you for your input. However, sprintf() does not seem to be the problem.

    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename*=utf-8''" . rawurlencode($filename));
    or
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename . "\"");

give the same result. The filename still is "__$%&_=_.txt".
It also tried different variations with mb_convert_encoding() etc.

Comment: Until I find a better way, it seems the most convenient thing is to actually transliterate.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, the issue has nothing to do with the encoding of the filename (`"Content-Disposition: attachment; filename*=utf-8''" . rawurlencode($filename)` option seems correct).

Some characters such as `?`, `<`, `>` are just [not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31976060/1180397) in filenames on particular platforms and replaced with `_` by a browser.

Also, you can have both `filename` and `filename*` params in `Content-Disposition` header, using the former as a fallback for client that doesn't support extended `filename*` param. It can be done seamlessly with [content-disposition](https://github.com/cardinalby/phpContentDisposition) lib.